# Assigning IP addresses to multiple switches

Tags: ip, network, dhcp, networking

Thank you in advance for taking the time to read my question, i appreciate it. I am in need of help on IP assigning to 4 brand NEW Araknis switches that I am replacing with the current netgear/tp-link switches I have.

What is the correct way to assign static IP addresses to switches? So for example lets say this is the current config on firewall and switches i have.

Firewall -153.0.0.1 and firewall is handling DHCP to assign IP PC's and the zone is 153.0.5.0-254
SW1 - 153.0.0.120
SW2 - 153.0.1.20
SW3 - 153.0.3.30
SW4 - 153.0.4.140

I do have AD setup and servers that are on static IP, very few PC's on static IP, cameras on static, share on static.

What is the correct way to assign IP's to switches? is there a order? Should I set the switches as DHCP and let firewall handle it?

Our business is not huge, we have like 100 employees, some are remote.

Thank you very much for your time, hope all of you are healthy and safe.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have an addressing scheme for how to assign addresses to devices. Apart from that, there are countless methods to organize addresses.

Layer-2 switches only require IP addresses for management, so you might want to put them in a management VLAN. You could assign management addresses via DHCP but most often, locally configured, static addresses are preferred to ensure management even when DHCP has failed. You should only use DHCP for important infrastructure with a redundant and resilient setup to avoid a domino effect.

Layer-3 switches also require IP addresses for their routing interfaces/gateways. These should be configured statically as well - you don't want your routing backbone to break because of some DHCP problem.

Answer (score 2):

There is no "correct" way, although I think most would say using DHCP is not a good idea.

Use any numbering scheme that makes sense to you and is easy to remember.

Answer (score 0):

Your can assign static ip to newly inducted switch from àvailable ip subnet pool. But make sure you static ip is new one from pool . And moreover exculde the static ip from DHCP pool .. so that DHCP won't allocate this ip to any PC's

Main point to remember exculde ip from DHCP pool and then allocate ip to new inducted switch

Ip DHCP excluded addressa x.x.x.x

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for your answers, I had completely lost track of this post. Yes I did assign static IP to all Araknis switches and exclude them from DHCP pool. DHCP is assigning IP's with no issues. All switches are working with default settings, i haven't ran into any issues with the switches. I am teaching myself about VLAN's trying to learn if VLAN's will give me better performance and management or even if I need it.

The company was in need of cable replacement too, there was many damaged cables, it took me weeks to drop new CAT6E cables, punched them down to new patch panels. The IT room is so clean now, lol.

I love it here because it gives me the keys to everything in IT, from firewall support to switches, servers, AD, DHCP, DNS, desktops, etc.... Anything in IT, im it.

Comment: Glad you got things working.  If any answer was helpful, please consider accepting it so it doesn't keep popping up in this list looking for an answer.

Comment: And welcome to NE!